# Adding docker metadata to logs in docker volumes with Filebeats and Elasticsearch

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logging, elastic-stack, filebeat

I'm using filebeats to collect docker console logs and send them to Elasticsearch. This works well since it also appends docker metadata (Ex: Container ID, Image etc..).
These containers run a Tomcat application. Other-than the logs printed to the console, it also creates logs in the `/usr/local/tomcat/logs` directory. I want to crawl these logs with filebeat aswell.

I have created a named volume mount to this directory and configured filebeats to read the `/var/lib/docker/<volume_name>/data/*log` logs.

However, logs crawled this way cannot have the `input` type `container`, since Filebeats tries to parse the log in a manner that fails due to formatting of the log files. Therefore I have set this to input type `log`

These logs appear in elasticsearch but without the docker metadata. I have the `add_docker_metadata` processor, but seems it's getting ignored.

Is there a way to get the docker metadata along with these logs?